# You can't play tetris like this!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, word-search

[image]

Transcript:

```
98TPO.D4Q7
RIFZ78JAPM
50.TS.S25U
N7.JU66A9N
2D742G89H2
60.N1ERT81
88D4DBSER2
T.3NAT4TI.
.9U6HY8.S2
636W1Z623R
```

**Note: OP messed up the orientation of a NUMPAD, so the intended orientation is stated as follows:**

```
123
456
789
 0
```

Hints:

> This puzzle is colorblind friendly.

> The title is connected to the solution, not the method to solving the grid.

Additional hints:

> I'm a Mac user so I actually don't have NUMPADS, which is the key to solving the puzzle.

> Start in the top left (brown) square, then follow the direction according to the numpad. (1 is up left, 2 is up, etc.)

Partial solutions and ideas are welcome in either the comment section or the answer section.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what tag this should be, unfortunately; what are the generic tags?

Comment: Note that rot13(N pbzchgre'f ahzcnq vf hcfvqr-qbja pbzcnerq gb n cubar'f ahzcnq.)

Comment: Oh really? I didn't know that... I'll update the question then

Comment: Does that mean that now the puzzle is trivial? @codewarrior0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now with the new hints, the answer gets quite trivial:

> By following the numbers and continuing on the same direction if the square we land on is not a number, we get this: [image: grid drawing updated] (stopping at the last full-stop)

This then gives us:

> I JUST DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY TETRIS HAS A NUMPAD OPTION (although there seems to be a missing full stop after the "A" in the grid

Which of course

> Is a fitting description for the title.

Comment: You haven't quite finished the message. The word OPTION should come next :)

Comment: The missing full stop is my mistake.

Comment: ah @Stiv i didn't exaclty see that, I'll add that in