# More than a 10x10 grid?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, word-search

Knowledge of my [previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125144/you-cant-play-tetris-like-this) is helpful but not required.

[image]

Transcript:

```
HEVMYC?.RE
.T.OUHINDM
AELS.SWOEU
V.Y.GD..NP
SNKNIRT.DS
TIOVEHJE.A
O..ETSOTA!
GBYHI.II.N
ANT.MADT!Y
```

### The key to the puzzle:

```
13 17 23
3000262633
3 7 12506381
41 270734467
23 295654927
7 41 167 5621491
11 13 2683007
23 113 37061 49139
19 37 67 787
3 17 73 23278091
40386532223
3 5693
3 43411 739031
1993 16057
```

**Note: OP messed up the orientation of a NUMPAD, so the intended orientation is stated as follows:**

```
123
456
789
 0
```

Hint:

> This is another color-blind friendly puzzle.

Additional Hints:

> Prime factorization + Numpad

> Each number is seen as a direction, e.g. 1 means left up, 2 means up, etc.

Partial solutions and ideas are welcome in either the comment section or the answer section.

Comment: Is there an error with the 146 numbers shouldn’t it be 144??

Comment: What are the 146 numbers?

Comment: In the key to the puzzle??

Comment: I presume you wanted it to be a square number in terms of the number of digits

Comment: No; the number of digits shouldn't matter. rot13 ahzore bs qvtvgf = yratgu bs zrffntr

Comment: Also you're not on the right path is you counted 146 numbers...

Comment: @PDT maybe you should look for the first additional hint

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150979/discussion-between-pdt-and-sny-smartie).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New user here, please tell me if I'm posting correctly.

> Multiply the primes in each line; this gives a number which we can map to the grid as follows: start at the upper left, then using the 5 as the current position, use the next key to determine the next character in the string. Combine the answers for every line.

However this gives

> 508330002626332626340011110011314768000633212694324421393836700014733144104921370684878666433279340386532223170799624622422332001601 which goes out of bounds at character 55 or so. I had to make two changes to the string to make the final answer make sense,

and after doing that, we get

> 50833000262633262634001111001131476800063321269432442**4**393836700014733144104921370684**6**78666433279340386532223170799624622422332001601 which gives `HAVE.YOU.EVER.WONDERED.WHY.I.LOVE.TEN.BY.TEN.GRIDS.SO.MUCH?.I.JUST.THINK.IT.IS.SO.ELEGANT.THAT.I.AM.ADDICTED.TO.IT!.I.HATE.NUMPADS!.`

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! Your answer is intended and correct.